# QGraphicsView level of detail handling

Tags: qt, qt4, pyqt4

I am working on a visualization SW which uses QGraphicsView and QGraphicsScene (Qt4.8, PyQt). I need LOD (level of detail) handling depending on zoom level. For this I create more QGraphicsScenes and I render the whole scene to each with different LOD level. (There is a QGraphicsScene for each LOD level).
I switch between these QGraphicsScenes depending on the zoom level. (QGraphicsView.setScene()).
The big problem is that the QGraphicsView's ScrollBars resets their positions when setScene() is called.

Here is a code snippet which tries to restore the ScrollBars values, but it doesn't work:

```
        hsb = self.horizontalScrollBar()
        vsb = self.verticalScrollBar()
        hv, vv = hsb.value(), vsb.value()
        self.lod = i
        self.setScene(self.scenes[self.lod])
        hsb.setValue(hv)    # this simply doesn't work !!!!
        vsb.setValue(vv)
```

Any idea to retain the positions of the ScrollBars? Or any idea for efficient LOD handling?
I could try to connect the ScrollBar's value changed signals into some custom slots which would disconnect from its own signal than re-set the ScrollBar's value from a saved one. That would be a very lame and ugly solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest to use a single scene to manage different level of details.
You can get the current level of detail directly inside the `QGraphicsItem::paint` method and draw the item accordingly.

Example C++:

```
void MyItem::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{
    qreal levelOfDetail = QStyleOptionGraphicsItem::levelOfDetailFromTransform(painter->worldTransform());
    //draw the item depending on the level of detail
}
```

Python

```
def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
    levelOfDetail = QStyleOptionGraphicsItem.optionlevelOfDetailFromTransform(painter.worldTransform())
    #draw the item depending on the level of detail
```

See [QStyleOptionGraphicsItem::levelOfDetailFromTransform](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleoptiongraphicsitem.html#levelOfDetailFromTransform) (for pyqt4 [QStyleOptionGraphicsItem.levelOfDetailFromTransform](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qstyleoptiongraphicsitem.html#levelOfDetailFromTransform) )

For large scene, with a lot of items, consider to group items. You can check the level of details when the scene transform (or the view transform) changes and show/hide the group of items. See [QGraphicsItemGroup](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qgraphicsitemgroup.html).

Comment: Hello! I also read about this kind of solution. But when you have about 100100 graphics items and you only want to display 100, it is quite inefficient to make the decision for every 100000 graphics items which won't be displayed. Isn't there a better solution?

Comment: Maybe you can group the items? Or create a sort of hierarchy? You can show/hide a group of items when the level of datail changes (you can check the level of datail when the scene (or the view) tansform changes).

Comment: Grouping seems to be a good idea. I'll look for that. Thanks!

Comment: Works (I haven't yet tested it with a lot of data). The paint() method also doesn't have to be overridden. It is enough to call show() and hide() for the groups.

Comment: It seems to be `levelOfDetail = QStyleOptionGraphicsItem.levelOfDetailFromTransform(painter.worldTransform())` instead of `levelOfDetail = QStyleOptionGraphicsItem.optionlevelOfDetailFromTransform(painter.worldTransform())`, at least in **PyQt5**.

For the import use `from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QStyleOptionGraphicsItem`.